# Tkinter: Grab content of a ScrolledText text pad

Tags: python, tkinter

all. I'm working on a simple Notepad-like program that saves files and closes the program when the escape key is pressed. I mention this because it is in this method that the program runs into problems. `textpad` is a `ScrolledText` object.

This line:

```
`contents = self.textPad.get(self, 1.0, END)`
```

results in the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1535, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "todopad.py", line 24, in save_and_quit
    contents = self.textPad.get(self, 1.0, END)
AttributeError: Event instance has no attribute 'textPad'
```

I know this is the problem, because the program executes and terminates without issue when this line is commented out. Although I don't understand the error at all.

This has been a very long-winded way of asking: How can I retrieve the contents of a ScrolledText text pad and save it to a variable or directly write it to a file? And also an explanation about the error message?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: As requested, here is the code for the entire thing.

```
import sys
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import *

root = Tkinter.Tk(className = "TodoPad");
textPad = ScrolledText(root, width = 80, height = 20)

def start_and_open():
    textFile = open('/home/colin/documents/prog/py/todopad/todo', 'r')
    contents = textFile.read()
    textPad.insert('1.0', contents)
    textFile.close()

def save_and_quit(self):
    textFile = open('/home/colin/documents/prog/py/todopad/todo', 'w')
    #contents = self.textPad.get(self, 1.0, END) # The line in question
    #textFile.write(contents)
    textFile.close()
    root.destroy()

textPad.pack()
root.bind('<Escape>', save_and_quit)
root.after(1, start_and_open)
root.mainloop()
```

Since I have posted the whole thing I may as well explain the rationale behind everything. It's supposed to be a fast little thing that opens a to-do list and displays what's already on the list in the text box. I make whatever edits I like, then it saves before closing when I hit escape, problem being is that it doesn't like closing because of the line that I mentioned previously in my post.

Comment: I may be help you, but could you post the whole code please? also, my question on codereview my interest you http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98007/linux-windows-text-editor-in-tkinter

Comment: Sure, I'll edit it into the main post.

Comment: thank you. i need to see the full code because i think i know what the problem is, and i suspect it lies with the way you organized your widgets

Comment: I formatted it manually before I saw this. Outside of mild bitterness this is a net gain. Thanks silent.

Comment: no problem. working on an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, kudos on identifying the problem.

### Placing the Widget

To answer what is going wrong: you need to actually place the widget into the window frame. You have a choice between `.grid()` and `.pack()`. The first allows you to pick exactly where you want it to go, the second puts in a (technically) default location.

Right now, the instance of your widget is not preset, so your program has no idea where to pull the value from. You have to set a location. i would recommend using `.grid()`, but for the example `.pack()` will work as well.

```
textPad = ScrolledText(root, width = 80, height = 20)
textPad.pack()
```

Try this, and see if it works. This should fix it, but I could be wrong.

Do NOT just do

```
textPad = ScrolledText(root, width = 80, height = 20).pack()
```

The `pack()` function returns a NULL and will nullify your widget.

### Your Issue With Self

Finally, why are you using self at all? You are not using any classes--you need to `global`ize the variable. The error that is thrown is a result of your program not knowing what class you are pulling the `self` instance from. Remove the `self` variables from the program, and put this into the function:

```
global textPad
```

This will make it `global` and all functions will be able to use it.

This should solve all the problems you have right now. However, give it a try and report what happens.

Here are some resources on global variables, getting input from widgets, and saving to files;

http://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/Python/Writing-to-Files/

Happy coding, and best of luck!!

Comment: Excellent, it worked! Thank you so much. I guess I was using `self` because the way I had it written it threw more errors than when I didn't have it, and my understanding of `self` wasn't good enough to know why I shouldn't have used it. Very philosophical. Thanks for the links, I'll be sure to check them out.

Comment: no problem and always happy to help. i had a very similar problem when i was working on a text editor of my own. well done handling the finding of the error, made fixing it much easier.